# How to detect layers in a PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to detect layers and extract them out of an PDF document.
Well I couldn't find any topics about detecting them, only how to create one.
This seems possible to me. Tried using SetaPDF and FPDF but can't get the layers extracted. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: What do you mean by "extact them out" exactly?

Comment: That it shows the found layers and possibly gives me some information about it.

Comment: What does "shows the found layers" mean (do you only need the name?) and what are "some information"? You can access layers (information) through SetaPDF-Core but it is not possible to access the content they are marking.

Comment: Just that it returns the found layers if there is one

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the layers of a PDF document you can use the [SetaPDF-Core](https://www.setasign.com/core) component (a product of us which is not free!). A simple iteration through all layers which were normally displayed in a GUI interface would look like this:

```
require_once 'SetaPDF/Autoload.php';

$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('paht/to/the.pdf');

$oc = $document->getCatalog()->getOptionalContent();
$iterator = $oc->getIterator();

foreach ($iterator AS $entry) {
    echo $iterator->getDepth() . ' ';
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $iterator->getDepth() * 4);
    if ($entry instanceof SetaPDF_Core_Document_OptionalContent_Group) {
        echo 'Layer: ' . $entry->getName();
    } elseif ($entry instanceof SetaPDF_Core_Type_StringValue) {
        echo '<i>Label: ' . SetaPDF_Core_Encoding::convertPdfString($entry->getValue()) . '</i>';
    } 
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Anyhow it is actually impossible to e.g. isolate the content of a specific layer and create a new document of it.

Accessing the state is possible throught the [`usage()`](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.Core.Document.OptionalContent.Group#method_usage) method:

```
$viewsState = $entry->usage()->getViewState();
```

Comment: Already tried this way but it didn't return anything for almost every PDF file I picked.

Comment: Without seeing such PDF file it is hard to say something about it. Feel free to share it or send it to support@setasign.com.